# NextAuth.js with nextjs 13 Custom Login Page Redirection Loop with Middleware - 307 Temporary Redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I'm facing an issue with NextAuth.js with Nextjs version 13 when using a custom page for login. Whenever I try to access `/auth/signin`, it redirects to `/login`, but then it redirects again to `/auth/signin`, creating a redirection loop. This issue only occurs when I have the following middleware enabled to protect the pages:

`middleware.ts`

```js
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware';
```

If I remove the middleware, everything works fine. I've gathered network details when this issue occurs:

Network Details:

- Request URL: `http://localhost:3000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F`
- Request Method: GET
- Status Code: 307 Temporary Redirect
- Remote Address: [::1]:3000
- Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response:

```
Connection: close
Date: Sun, 16 Jul 2023 17:35:12 GMT
Location: /api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=%2Flogin%3FcallbackUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252F
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

NextAuth Configuration:

```
import NextAuth, { Session } from 'next-auth';
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import useRequest from '../../../../hooks/useRequest';

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      // ... (credentials provider configuration)
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }: { token: any; user: any }) {
      // ... (jwt callback configuration)
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },
    async session({ session, token }: { session: Session; token: any }) {
      // ... (session callback configuration)
      session.user = token as any;
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

[image: network]

Can someone help me understand why this redirection loop is happening and how to resolve it? It seems to be related to the custom login page and the middleware used for protecting pages. Any insights or suggestions to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your middleware.ts with something like below:

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default withAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",    
  },
});
```